# node.js spawn python child process on Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: python, node.js, virtual-machine, child-process

I have right now a node.js backend where I'm spawning a Python child_process. The Python file executes successfully and returns the data correctly. However in production, the node.js backend will run on a linux server and the python script needs to be run in a Windows environment.

Is there any possible way to spawn the python process directly on a Windows Virtual Machine instead of the current server? If not, what would be possible alternatives besides using a Windows server for node.js?

I don't think, that in this case the versions really matter, but here they are:

- node.js 12.16.2
- Python: 3.8.2
- Linux server: Ubuntu

Comment: "the python script needs to be run in a Windows environment" - I guess the answer depends on how badly it needs to be run in a Windows environment. Have you tried running it on Linux? If you're running this on _your own server_, then sure, you can spin up whatever virtual machines you need, but if you're using some service like Heroku, I don't think they'll let you have VMs

Comment: Yes I tried. The script depends on an COM interface and therefore I see no other way than running it on Windows. I'm also running it on my own server. My question really refers to, how to spawn it not on my linux server,  but instead on the virtual machine (in node.js I just have to name the path of the python script).